# How do I use NodeJS on Asustor AS-302T NAS

Tags: node.js, npm

I have recently bought a [Asustor AS-302T NAS](http://www.asustor.com/product?p_id=16), which is an absolutely brilliant solution for the home. One of it's most impressive features is that you can install apps which extends the ordinary behavior of a NAS. And if you are a developer you can also create your own apps.

While apps are fun, I have more interest in using my NAS as a kitchen-sink for my personal nodejs projects. In short I want to run nodejs application that I can then call from various other machines around the house. My own mini-cloud for IOT experiments.

**Installing, one click only**

Having installed NodeJS through [App-Central](http://www.asustor.com/apps/app_detail?id=114) I am at a loss how exactly to start using NodeJS on my NAS. The whole installation is essentially an on/off switch with no options or visible settings at all. I can find no documentation on practical tasks like uploading a nodejs application, deal with access rights or even execute it.

[image: No options what so ever]

Under Windows or OS-X I would use npm via the command-line or shell, but Asustor is a purely html based interface (with the exception of XBMC through HDMI).

Why offer to users the option of installing NodeJS -if it's impossible to actually use it?

So my question has three aspects to it:

1. How do i get access to npm on my Asustor NAS
2. How do i get my NodeJS application running
3. Is it possible to run my application as a service (executed when the NAS boots)?

Comment: You can connect to NAS via ssh (enabled in Settings > Terminal). Also you can install Shell In A Box from App Central which provides ssh interface to your browser. NodeJS installation from App Central is a replacement for linux package manager (e.g. apt-get install nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

From the [ASUSTOR Developer's Guide](http://developer.asustor.com/document/App_Central_Developer_Guide_2.0.0_0801.pdf): apps are installed into 
`/usr/local/AppCentral/$APP_NAME`.

NodeJS executables will be at path `/usr/local/AppCentral/nodejs/bin/node` and `/usr/local/AppCentral/nodejs/bin/npm`.

You can login to NAS via SSH and add them to PATH variable, or create symlinks...

I'm also searching for solution how to run them as a service (daemon), maybe an /etc/init.d script might help.